# how I get new contract

Tags: solidity, verify, contract, remix

I want a solidity contract to compile and deploy in remix.ethereum

the contract code I used brings always errors!

Error message:

> This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent’s methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract’s constructor correctly.

I want to use a new contract to verify and publish my tokens.

can you help me pls with a new contract that works with a remix and verifying etherscan?

regards

Comment: Please provide the contract code and errors in the question.

Comment: we have published the contract with an error message here: 

https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/pragma-solidity-0-5-0/6121

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, you are trying to deploy the `ERC20Interface` instead of the contract `x`.

The solution is simple in Remix: Chose the correct contract to deploy from the selectbox.

[image: Selectbox selecting the contract to deploy]

Comment: done, it works, I get a hash address too,  when I go to https://bscscan.com/ on the search bar  I paste the hash address to see the token, it gave me this: Search Not Found
Sorry, We are unable to locate this TxnHash

Comment: BscScan only provides an overview of the current state of the blockchain such as your transaction status, but we have no control over these transactions.

Comment: 1) If you have just submitted a transaction please wait for at least 30 seconds before refreshing this page.
2) It could still be in the TX Pool of a different node, waiting to be broadcasted.
3) When the network is busy it can take a while for your transaction to propagate through the network and for us to index it.
4) If it still does not show up after 1 hour, please check with your sender/exchange/wallet/transaction provider for additional information.

Comment: The deployed contract address is valid only within the Remix local network. It's not deployed on the mainnet... Deploying on public testnets and mainnet is a whole another topic. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Binance smart chain, but for Ethereum contracts, I'd start here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/deploying/ And my guess is that BSC is going to be similar.

Comment: is there any way to transfer some eth from Rinkeby to mainnet in meta mask?
or is there any website that gives some eth for mainnet in meta mask?

Comment: Rinkeby and mainnet are separate networks, so there's no way to transfer data and ETH between the two networks... Sites that give you small fraction of ETH in exchange for watching ads are called faucets. You'll find some after a bit of googling. Be aware there is a large portion of scam sites that will promise you to give you ETH after XY days of clicking on ads, but they never do. However, this is not my area of expertise so I don't know of any currently working faucets and would recommend buying ETH through a reputable exchange such as Binance or Coinbase.